# This is about the setCheckInTable function at the bottom of my code. It does not populate the entire 2D array with -1s it just loop twice

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

**here is the main function it is not letting me set the array full of -1s I want to fill the array with the call function setCheckInTable(); but it is not reaching past checkInTable[0][1] i am down bad right now**

```
int main()
{   

int checkRow = 5;
int checkCol = 2;

int checkInTable[checkRow][checkCol];

setCheckInTable(checkInTable, checkRow, checkCol)

return 0
}
```

**this is the function that is not working properly**

```
void setCheckInTable(int** arr, int rows, int cols){

int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = -1;
                
                printf("This is i: ");
                printf("%d \n", i);
                printf("This is j: ");
                printf("%d \n", + j);
            }

        }   
}
```

Comment: Do you have a visible prototype for `setCheckInTable`? You define a function expecting a pointer to a pointer but you pass an array. Arrays are no pointers. They have very different memory layout.

Comment: Try this: `void setCheckInTable(int rows, int cols, int arr[][cols])`

Comment: BTW: What do you mean with "only goes up 4 to loops"? What happens then? Function returns? Crash and Burn due to illegal memory access? Smoke comes out of the CPU?

Comment: Again: What happens after those 4 loops? Please also answer my other questions.

Comment: @Gerhardh I get this output: This is i: 0
This is j: 0
This is i: 0
This is j: 1 Meaning the loops twice sorry.

Comment: @Gerhardh then this error: 88 6 [Warning] conflicting types for 'setCheckInTable'

Comment: When you tried to use my fix, did you realize that you must update the function call accordingly?

Comment: Yes I tried it, the function proto is outside of main() it did not work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing arrays with pointers.
While arrays can decay to a pointer in some scenarious, they are still something very different:
An object of type `int[x][y]` will consume memory of the size `x*y*sizeof(int)`.
An object of type `int**` will only consume memory of the size of a pointer.

You need to fix your function signature and provide a prototype:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void setCheckInTable(int rows, int cols, int arr[][cols]);

int main()
{   
    int checkRow = 5;
    int checkCol = 2;

    int checkInTable[checkRow][checkCol];

    setCheckInTable(checkRow, checkCol, checkInTable);

    return 0;
}


void setCheckInTable(int rows, int cols, int arr[][cols])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = -1;
            
            printf("This is i, j: %d %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -Wextra -Wall
<no errors or warnings>
$ ./test
This is i, j: 0 0
This is i, j: 0 1
This is i, j: 1 0
This is i, j: 1 1
This is i, j: 2 0
This is i, j: 2 1
This is i, j: 3 0
This is i, j: 3 1
This is i, j: 4 0
This is i, j: 4 1
$
```